# Api routes for multiple get methods

Tags: api, get, routes

I have two Get methods in my api as below :

```
public IHttpActionResult GetCandidateProfilesByProfileID(long id)
{
......
}
```

and

```
public IHttpActionResult GetCandidatesBySearchCrietria( string FName= null,string LastName = null, Nullable<DateTime> DoB = null, string City = null,string zipCode = null, string stateID = null,string education = null,
{
...
}
```

How to configure routes for these? I am having issues invoking them with the default route.

Thanks,
Mahantesh

Comment: Does my answer help you or do I need to update the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using Web Api 2. You can use the [Route attribute](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/):

In order to make http attribute routing available you'll have to add the following line in `App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs`:

```
static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    }
}
```

And then add the route attribute to the method.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetCandidateProfilesByProfileID")]
public IHttpActionResult GetCandidateProfilesByProfileID(long id)
{
    ......
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("GetCandidatesBySearchCrietria")]
public IHttpActionResult GetCandidatesBySearchCrietria( string FName= null,string LastName = null, Nullable<DateTime> DoB = null, string City = null,string zipCode = null, string stateID = null,string education = null)
{
    ...
}
```

Please note that certain parameters are required. If omitted this will result in *Http 404 Not Found*.

In asp.net Core you can use the *HttpGet* attribute:

```
[HttpGet("GetCandidateProfilesByProfileID")]
public IHttpActionResult GetCandidateProfilesByProfileID(long id)
{
    ......
}

[HttpGet("GetCandidatesBySearchCrietria")]
public IHttpActionResult GetCandidatesBySearchCrietria( string FName= null,string LastName = null, Nullable<DateTime> DoB = null, string City = null,string zipCode = null, string stateID = null,string education = null)
{
    ...
}
```